# changing main content on ng-repeat item click

Tags: angularjs

here is the plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Qj2yxQuT7SZ19u3vuXyq?p=preview

like an inbox.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 leftnav">

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add News</button>
    <br>

    <article ng-repeat="x in issues | filter:query" ng-click="makeActive(i)">
        <h4>{{x.title}}</h4>
        <p>{{x.message | limitTo:numLimit}}</p>
        <a href="">Read More..</a>
    </article>

</div>

<div class="col-xs-8 main-content">
    <h2>News</h2>
    <hr>

    <article ng-repeat="x in issues">
        <h3 >{{x.title}}</h3>
        <p>{{x.priority}}</p>
        <p class="lead">{{x.author}} - 6/12/2014</p>
        <!-- ng-if="x.author == 'Andy' " -->
        <hr>
        <p>{{x.message}}</p>
        <a href="">Read More</a>
        <hr>
    </article>
</div>
```

having a list of items ng-repeat on the left, then selecting the main content (on the right) from the options, then displaying the full content as the main selection.

ng-if ? ng-show ?

not sure how well I've described this but it should be pretty obvious from the fiddle.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9qZsp2o22L5x1a0JofPy?p=preview

1. I create a `currectIssue` variable for your right content display.
2. In left content, `<a href="">Read More..</a>` has been change to `<a ng-click="showIssue(x)">Read More..</a>`

Answer (score 0):

updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/hGsdkybRMoRct8VykCcB?p=preview

well, you might consider:
- use another scope variable to display the selected item from the object
- I'd use ng-if in this case as that will create/destroy the content as needed

```
// controller
$scope.selectIssue = function(x) {
  $scope.issue = x;
}

$scope.selectIssue($scope.issues['1']);

//view 

<article>
  <h3 >{{issue.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{issue.priority}}</p>
  <p class="lead">{{issue.author}} - 6/12/2014</p>
  <div ng-if="issue.author == 'Andy'">
    <hr>
    <p>{{issue.message}}</p>
    <a href="">Read More</a>
    <hr>
  </div>
</article>
```